# Check modified date of a folder and output a message if it was not modified today

Tags: powershell

Please help to achieve my below requirement in powershell, I am very new in scripting :(

We have a folder like:

- c:\folder\Folder1\TEST
- c:\folder\Folder2\TEST
- c:\folder\Folder3\TEST
- c:\folder\Folder4\TEST

Check folder date for `TEST`, if date equals today, then do nothing. But if date is not today, then output `"FolderX not updated from yesterday"`

Comment: stackoverflow is not a script writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want. Use `Get-Childitem` to find the `TEST` files, `where` to filter those that haven't been modified today and then `Split-Path` to get the folder part of the path. All together this looks like

```
Get-ChildItem folder\*\TEST | where lastwritetime -lt ([datetime]::Today) | Split-Path -Parent
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, As i am not aware about powershell can you help me to achieve working script, As i tried above it not giving me output..             Get-ChildItem D:\Work\Test\*.*\TEST | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | Split-Path -paren